# How to run laradock w/ nginx-proxy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I've created an `nginx-proxy`/ `letsencrypt` environment by following [this tutorial](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/host-multiple-ssl-websites-docker-nginx/), which is working great.

I now want to create a `laradock` environment that leverages the `nginx-proxy` environment, so that it's sites can live alongside my other (non laradock) sites, on the single server.

1. What's the best way to do this?
2. Where in the `laradock` docker-compose.yml do I add the `nginx-proxy` fields?
3. Do I remove the nginx block from the `laradock` docker-compose.yml?
4. Is there else I'm missing / should do differently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Directory structure:**

Each of the following directories has it's own `docker-compose.yml`:

```
- laradock
- laradock-site-1
- laradock-site-2
- nginx-proxy
- nginx-proxy-site-1
- nginx-proxy-site-2
```

**Needed fields for `nginx-proxy`:**

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

```
environment:
  VIRTUAL_HOST: sub.domain.com
  LETSENCRYPT_HOST: sub.domain.com
  LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: email@domain.com
```

```
expose:
  - 80
```

**`laradock` - docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  redis:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}

services:

### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
          - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
          - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
          - INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_WP_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WP_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - COMPOSER_AUTH=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_AUTH}
          - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
          - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PING=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PING}
          - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
          - INSTALL_POWERLINE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_POWERLINE}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
      tty: true
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker

### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_POSTGIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_POSTGIS}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_CALENDAR=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR}
          - INSTALL_FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_APCU=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_APCU}
          - INSTALL_YAML=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_YAML}
          - INSTALL_RDKAFKA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_RDKAFKA}
          - INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PING=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PING}
          - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
          - ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${PHP_FPM_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_XHPROF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XHPROF}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
      expose:
        - "9000"
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
        - FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_FAKETIME}
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      networks:
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker

### PHP Worker ############################################
    php-worker:
      build:
        context: ./php-worker
        args:
          - PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GMP}
          - PUID=${PHP_WORKER_PUID}
          - PGID=${PHP_WORKER_PGID}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ./php-worker/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      networks:
        - backend

### Laravel Horizon ############################################
    laravel-horizon:
      build:
        context: ./laravel-horizon
        args:
          - PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_SOCKETS=${LARAVEL_HORIZON_INSTALL_SOCKETS}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ./laravel-horizon/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      networks:
        - backend

### NGINX Server #########################################
    nginx:
      build:
        context: ./nginx
        args:
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
        - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
        - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
      ports:
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### MySQL ################################################
    mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend

### Redis ################################################
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      networks:
        - backend

### Certbot #########################################
    # certbot:
    #   build:
    #     context: ./certbot
    #   volumes:
    #     - ./data/certbot/certs/:/var/certs
    #     - ./certbot/letsencrypt/:/var/www/letsencrypt
    #   environment:
    #     - CN="sub.domain.com"
    #     - EMAIL="email@domain.com"
    #   networks:
    #     - frontend

### Mailhog ################################################
    mailhog:
      build: ./mailhog
      ports:
        - "1025:1025"
        - "8025:8025"
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Docker-in-Docker ################################################
    docker-in-docker:
      image: docker:dind
      privileged: true
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
      expose:
        - 2375
      networks:
        - backend
```

**`laradock` - .env:**

```
###########################################################
###################### General Setup ######################
###########################################################

### Paths #################################################

# Point to the path of your applications code on your host
APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../

# Point to where the `APP_CODE_PATH_HOST` should be in the container
APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER=/var/www

# You may add flags to the path `:cached`, `:delegated`. When using Docker Sync add `:nocopy`
APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG=:cached

# Choose storage path on your machine. For all storage systems
DATA_PATH_HOST=~/.laradock/data

### Drivers ################################################

# All volumes driver
VOLUMES_DRIVER=local

# All Networks driver
NETWORKS_DRIVER=bridge

### Docker compose files ##################################

# Select which docker-compose files to include. If using docker-sync append `:docker-compose.sync.yml` at the end
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml

# Change the separator from : to ; on Windows
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:

# Define the prefix of container names. This is useful if you have multiple projects that use laradock to have seperate containers per project.
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=laradock

### PHP Version ###########################################

# Select a PHP version of the Workspace and PHP-FPM containers (Does not apply to HHVM). Accepted values: 7.3 - 7.2 - 7.1 - 7.0 - 5.6
PHP_VERSION=7.3

### Phalcon Version ###########################################

# Select a Phalcon version of the Workspace and PHP-FPM containers (Does not apply to HHVM). Accepted values: 3.4.0+
PHALCON_VERSION=3.4.1

### PHP Interpreter #######################################

# Select the PHP Interpreter. Accepted values: hhvm - php-fpm
PHP_INTERPRETER=php-fpm

### Docker Host IP ########################################

# Enter your Docker Host IP (will be appended to /etc/hosts). Default is `10.0.75.1`
DOCKER_HOST_IP=10.0.75.1

### Remote Interpreter ####################################

# Choose a Remote Interpreter entry matching name. Default is `laradock`
PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=laradock

### Windows Path ##########################################

# A fix for Windows users, to ensure the application path works
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

### Environment ###########################################

# If you need to change the sources (i.e. to China), set CHANGE_SOURCE to true
CHANGE_SOURCE=false

### Docker Sync ###########################################

# If you are using Docker Sync. For `osx` use 'native_osx', for `windows` use 'unison', for `linux` docker-sync is not required
DOCKER_SYNC_STRATEGY=native_osx

###########################################################
################ Containers Customization #################
###########################################################

### WORKSPACE #############################################

WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=true
WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_AUTH=false
WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE=true
WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION=node
WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY=
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN=false
WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION=latest
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=true
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XSL=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_CASSANDRA=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH=false
WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION=8.1.17
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WP_CLI=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_POWERLINE=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TAINT=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PING=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSHPASS=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_INOTIFY=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FSWATCH=false
WORKSPACE_PUID=1000
WORKSPACE_PGID=1000
WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=2.42
WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE=UTC
WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT=2222
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG=false
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL=false

### PHP_FPM ###############################################

PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XHPROF=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CASSANDRA=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XSL=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TAINT=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_POSTGIS=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PCNTL=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_RDKAFKA=false
PHP_FPM_FAKETIME=-0
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_APCU=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_YAML=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PING=false
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSHPASS=false
PHP_FPM_FFMPEG=false
PHP_FPM_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES="es_ES.UTF-8 fr_FR.UTF-8"

### PHP_WORKER ############################################

PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PGSQL=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_BCMATH=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PHALCON=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SOAP=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_AMQP=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SWOOLE=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_TAINT=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_FFMPEG=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GMP=false
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_CASSANDRA=false

PHP_WORKER_PUID=1000
PHP_WORKER_PGID=1000

### NGINX #################################################

NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80
NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT=443
NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH=./logs/nginx/
NGINX_SITES_PATH=./nginx/sites/
NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000
NGINX_SSL_PATH=./nginx/ssl/

### LARAVEL_HORIZON ################################################

LARAVEL_HORIZON_INSTALL_SOCKETS=false
LARAVEL_HORIZON_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true

### APACHE ################################################

APACHE_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80
APACHE_HOST_HTTPS_PORT=443
APACHE_HOST_LOG_PATH=./logs/apache2
APACHE_SITES_PATH=./apache2/sites
APACHE_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
APACHE_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000
APACHE_PHP_UPSTREAM_TIMEOUT=60
APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/

### MYSQL #################################################

MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

### REDIS #################################################

REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**`nginx-proxy` - docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.1
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"

  dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen:0.7.3
    container_name: nginx-proxy-gen
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - dockergen
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy-gen
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:

# Do not forget to 'docker network create nginx-proxy' before launch, and to add '--network nginx-proxy' to proxied containers. 

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: I got the impression that you are using Laradock for production, but this is a stack primarily meant to be used in development, thus if this is the case I would advise you against using it in production from a security perspective. The docs even show to execute things with the root user, and that is very insecure for a production server, plus  the Dockerfiles seem to have all batteries included, and that may be awesome for development, but bad for security in production, and may even affect performance.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look to Traefik, that is a proxy developed specifically for containers and can handle creation and renovation of LetsEncrypt certificates on the fly. See their docs https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that Laradock wasn't intended for production... I did minimize the docker-compose.yml / env to only include the parts that I needed, but it sounds like that's not enough? If I were to add some security measures in place (topic for a different discussion), is this still bad practice? Should I be attempting to create a Laravel friendly container from scratch?

Regarding Traefik, it just sounds like an alternative to the `nginx-proxy` / `docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` that I currently have in place. Is there any benefits to using Traefik instead?

Comment: Traefik was designed from scratch for docker containers and manages new domains automatically, by creating a new LetsEncrypt certificate and renovate them, without any human intervention.

Comment: A production image must strictly have only the dependencies it needs for the application you are running on, thus you should start from a Alpine image or if not possible from a Debian slim, and then just add what you need. This will reduce tremendously the attack surface on your application, thus improving security. Always scan your docker images for vulnerabilities with a tool like https://github.com/coreos/clair/ and you will see that Alpine based ones always have less issues then others.

Comment: As a reference you can look to this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/exadra37/php7-fpm/dockerfile) I made to be used in this [Php Docker Stack](https://packagist.org/packages/exadra37-docker/php-docker-stack), and you will see that contains only minimal dependencies, that make a good starting point to build other images. Bear in mind that I am not maintaining actively both projects I linked, just use them to learn.The Php Docker Stack was built from scratch with production in mind and then the images for development are built by extending the productions ones, not the other way around.

Comment: Cool man, thanks for the tips! I'm very new to docker so all of this is very helpful.